# Problems with saving to an existing xml in managed c

Tags: xml, c++-cli

I need to update an existing xml-File, that i have loaded before
in c++/cli and have already tried doing that with XmlDocument and XmlWriter
but i always get an IOException.
I've already confirmed that there is no part of my programm currently modifying my xml, so there should be no problem.
I'm clueless what to do now. That's a part of my code for this function.

```
        XmlDocument ^doc;
        doc->Load("Test.xml");
        XmlNode ^node;
        XmlWriterSettings ^settings = gcnew XmlWriterSettings();
             settings->Indent=true;
             settings->NewLineOnAttributes = true;
             XmlWriter ^writer;
             writer= XmlWriter::Create("Test.xml",settings);
             node->WriteTo(writer);

             try
             {
                  doc->Save(writer);
             }
             catch(IOException ^e)
             { 

             }
```

Comment: PS what does the IO exception say is wrong?

Comment: It says that a process is currently occupying the file; the file is not read only

Comment: First things first, if you write to newtest.xml does it work?

Comment: In C# I'd be using new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) load doc from the stream and do that in a using block, then similar for writing. I never use doc load and save with a file name in production code.

Comment: If i write to a different file it works just perfect; I'm asking if thats possible in c++/cli and not how it might be done in c#. Sorry but i've already set once everything back to zero and i'm not in the mood to do that again

Comment: Um, well if nothing else is using the file, and writing to a new file works, that would suggest that the Someone else using the file, is in fact the read to fill the document. If so your mood is irrelevant.

Comment: In fact i'm not using the read to fill the document but rather to get a single node out of the xml, whose attributes i wish to alter. I had the same idea but no solution for that problem.

Comment: Huh? This is relevant how?.Open the file for reading, load the document, close the file. Find the node, change it . Open the file for writing, write, close the file. If you wish to lock the document for the the transaction. Use your code as is, except for saving to a temp file, then rename on success.

Comment: i just found the mistake. Its actually something i should have recognized before. Its working now.

Comment: You shoul answer your own question then. Accept it and win a sock puppet hat and 15 points. More to the point, someone else might get something out of this post.